# Android ADT 20.0.2 not registering in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I'm trying to add the Android ADT plug-in into eclipse. It downloads and installs fine, there are no errors, but the changes don't show up when I restart eclipse. I'm using Juno but I have tried this on Indigo as well and got the same problem. I am working on windows 7, 64 bit.The eclipse versions are 32 bit. 
I've tried running as administrator, moving the folder to c:/eclipse..., running from the command line with eclipse -clean. I've tried new installs multiple times. 
In help - about eclipse - Installation Details - Installed Software, Android Development Tools shows up. When I go to windows - preferences, android doesn't show up on the left. I can see the com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_20.0.2.v201207191942-407447 file in the plug-in folder along with the other ones. 
To install Eclipse, all I did was download the zip, open with windows explorer, and move the eclipse folder into the desktop. The file structure is unchanged.

I also tried deleting .eclipse and.android folders in the c:/users. 
And I tried downloading the zip file to my desktop and installing software with the archive button. No luck.

Just wondering, do you need the Android sdk to be installed before the ADT?

Hoping its something simple. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you downloading the plugin archive and dropping it the "droppings" folder yourself, or using the update feature from the IDE? Also, you should try another plugin, something innocuous, to see if you get a better result.

Comment: I use Install new Software, then add the https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ I tried adding a new view but couldn't find it so I guess the problem is with plug-ins in general.

Comment: Well, installed the 64 bit eclipse and jdk. While doing so I uninstalled my old jdk's. What ever changed, it's working now. I can't answer my own question now but i will when it lets me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem was but I installed 64 bit Juno and 64 bit Java JDK. I removed older jdk's which may have been part of the problem. For whatever reason, it's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use Win7 64 bit as well, Eclipse (indigo and Juno) 32bit and ADT and working ok.
I am using Eclipse for Java Developers

On Installed Software you should see for the ADT: (make sure you installed all when Installing new software) You need all items that are shown except the NDK except if plan to code in C++;
Mine shows this on Installed Software:
Android DDMS
Android Development Tools
Android hierarchy Viewer
Android Traceview

Also remember you need the android SDK for development which is a separate installer.
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Ya, I installed all and can see the adt in installed software. Without the adt adding the android option in the window preferences I can't point eclipse to the sdk. Where is your eclipse installed?

Comment: I tried eclipse for java developers, eclipse java ee, and java classic. They all behave the same.